# IE download html file instead of opening on Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

I deploy my site on glassfish server.
My site run ok on Chrome, Firefox, opera.. but it not work on IE browser.
My IE Browse auto save the html file instead opening it.
Please help! Thanks so much!

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  And if IE10 or below perhaps consider not supporting that browser anymore.

Comment: I using IE 11, i think it isn't problem. I think this problem at glassfish but i don't know exactly. Thank you so much!